# Where to keep socket.on in react to always be listening even if user is not on page

Tags: reactjs, socket.io

I am working on a react app that is using socket.io. I need the socket to be always listening and calling a function to handle some data to be sent back to the backend. I put the socket.on in the component did mount of my app.js but I realize that the user has to be on the page for the function to be called. Is there someplace else I have to call the function so that it can be always on regardless of whether the user is on the page? And I also realize that the socket will somehow have to be always initialized? Or is this not the right way to go about it? I'm new to sockets in general any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

you can listen the socket in any of the jsx file that will be active if the application is switched on for example you can have a lifecycle event say **componentDidUpdate** in the **route.js** file it is one of the file that will be active thorugh out the application

Comment: But the request is likely going to be sent at like 3:30 in the morning when no one is awake to use the site, is there a way that I can call it that is not dependent on the person being on the site?

Comment: that's not the case because main use of socket io is to feed live data while the user is active if the user is not active then there is no point to have socket , since there will be api called when the user starts the application

Comment: @scotth527 why do you care if it is being called at 3:30 am in the morning if nobody is there? You are worrying the event will not fire, but then saying nobody will be there anyway...